Lamba Expression Iterator in Jetpack Composable Objects
Currently I am following, the the codelab from android with the the link.
In the following snippet, I do understand that account parameter, which is notated as
** account ** in the snippet, is iterating over data argument of OverViewScreenCard, which is equal to UserData.accounts. But I am still curious, how it is assigned in such way?
@Composable
private fun AccountsCard(onClickSeeAll: () -> Unit, onAccountClick: (String) -> Unit) {
    val amount = UserData.accounts.map { account -> account.balance }.sum()
    OverviewScreenCard(
        title = stringResource(R.string.accounts),
        amount = amount,
        onClickSeeAll = onClickSeeAll,
        data = UserData.accounts,
        colors = { it.color },
        values = { it.balance }
    ) { **account** ->
        AccountRow(
            modifier = Modifier.clickable { onAccountClick(account.name) },
            name = account.name,
            number = account.number,
            amount = account.balance,
            color = account.color
        )
    }
}


Is it like somehow a behavior of a certain syntax?

AccountRow is placed in curly braces. In this case that means it is the last parameter of OverviewScreenCard. It's just a Kotlin feature that the parameter can also be moved outside the round parentheses of OverviewScreenCard. It can also be conventionally written like this:
OverviewScreenCard(
    // ... other parameters
    values = { it.balance },
    row = { account ->
        AccountRow(
            // ... other parameters
        )
    }
)

Now it becomes clear that the braces actually belong to the lamba that is passed to the row parameter of OverviewScreenCard. account is therefore the parameter that will be passed to the lambda. When you look at the implementation of OverviewScreenCard you will find the row is used like this:
data.take(SHOWN_ITEMS).forEach { row(it) }

This means that the data list is shortened to the first SHOWN_ITEMS items (which just is a constant for 3) and that for each value of that shortened list, the row lambda is executed with it as the parameter. it is the current item in the for each loop, therefore one of the first three accounts in data.
That's why you can access the account variable in the lambda.
